# How to use admob ID for each application

Tags: android, admob

Hello everyone and thanks for the hard work
My question is 
For example if i create 2 applications 
Should i use the same admob ID in the 2 of my applications ??
If not how can i get an admob ID for each application
And thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add both applications to admob, each with different package name, a unique ID will be generated for each of your apps. You will have to use those id's. If you use the same id in multiple projects, the only project which will show ads will be the one whose package name matches with the package name registered against that admob-id.

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer

Comment: U're welcome. Please up-vote as well @ÃbdélkãdérÃzhãr :)